# Webpack add fonts

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, webpack

I am using [this](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) repo. How am I suppose to add custom fonts? I have made folder called "fonts" in assets and I have put my fonts there.

fonts.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  src: url('../assets/font/Lato-Regular.eot');
  src: url('../assets/font/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../assets/font/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('../assets/font/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../assets/font/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Also I have added configuration for fonts and add it to app.modules.ts.

```
import '../styles/fonts.scss';
```

My questions what code should I add to webpack to make it work.

Comment: in your webpack.config.js add this {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
 }

Comment: module: { loaders: [] { test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' } }

Comment: does it make sense?

Comment: if this is your webpack configuration file then yes

Comment: according to git repo this is your config file https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: aah right you are right ...

Comment: use the webpack.dev.js

Comment: I have ask simple question. Your comments did not answer it

Comment: I m being helpful and you are moaning. i am not magician, i am trying to help you. if not than then good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading your font files relative to the CSS file created by the webpack loader & extractor. I took a quick look at that boilerplate, and it includes the sass loader already.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: 'css-loader!sass-loader'
  }),
  include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
},
```

It should work if you have your fonts in the right folder.